# regex in string and output in 2 diffrent columns bash

Tags: macos, bash, regex

I'm on macOS Mojave and trying to use regex to output the results of a match in 2 different columns

I have a file that contains these strings:

```
JJ1111-Aaaaaa-AB-22222222-f_2-777777_S1_L000_trtrt
JJ1111-Baaaaa-AB-22322222-f_2-777777_S1_L000_trtrt
JJ1111-Caaaaa-AB-22222322-f_2-777777_S1_L000_trtrt
```

I want to extract the "Aaaaaa" (or the string of 6 consecutive charaters) and the String of 2 capital letters "AB".

Now the command

```
egrep -oh '[a-zA-Z]{6}' my.txt
```

will return

```
Aaaaaa
Baaaaa
Caaaaa
```

And

```
egrep -oh '\-[A-Z]{2}' my.txt | sed 's/-//g'
```

will return

```
AB
AB
AB
```

Is there a way (I'm thinking using awk), to output the two matches in a new file with 2 columns that are separated with tabs? I've tried this:

```
awk '{$1 ~ /[a-zA-Z]{6}/; print $1}' my.txt
```

But only gives me the original string of characters

Comment: There isn't any separator in the input. Try making `-` a separator `awk -F'-' '$2 ~ /[a-zA-Z]{6}/ && $3 ~ /[A-Z]{2}/ {print $2"\t"$3}'`

Answer (score 1):

I think the most straightforward tool here is `cut`:

`cut -sf 2,3 -d '-' --output-delimiter=$'\t' my.txt > output.txt`

As you can see, using `-` as delimiter, it fetches the 2nd and 3rd fields and converts the dash in a tab. The output is written to `output.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already made up working regex'es... why not continue use them:
If you have the data in 'inputfile'

```
sed -rne 's/.*([a-zA-Z]{6})\-([A-Z]{2}).*/\1\t\2/p' <inputfile
```

add
 `| od -t x1z -w10`

... at the end and you will see this, to verify what you get:

```
0000000 41 61 61 61 61 61 09 41 42 0a  >Aaaaaa.AB.<
0000012 42 61 61 61 61 61 09 41 42 0a  >Baaaaa.AB.<
0000024 43 61 61 61 61 61 09 41 42 0a  >Caaaaa.AB.<
0000036
```